# get div above picture to have same height as it

Tags: html, css

This might be two questions in one, I'll strat with the actual one.
I want to build a website that is simple and that is mostly out off pictures. Those pictures are set so resize automaticly between 1280px and 640px - that works fine.
BUT now I want to have a div that slides in above each picture once you hover above it. 
The sliding in can be archived with css or java that I know, the problem is that the div with the text does not resize as the picture does. In other words putting it to 100% height and 100% width doesn't fix it to the picture size. Is there a way to have it always the same size as the picture below it?!

Right now the height is set to 360px because thats how I left it but here is the link to my testpage so you can take a look at what I mean.

[www.panorama-publishing.de/theme-dev](http://www.panorama-publishing.de/theme-dev)

thank you in advance! let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: You could set the container to whatever height and width that you want and make both the image and the div overlay inherit those heights and widths

Comment: if the text div is before the image, it will not inherit the same size via width and height:100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you resize the div containing the picture and not the other div (call it overlay, if you will). Then you can set the picture to be 100% of the parent div and the overlay can slide from top to bottom and be as big as the entire screen, if you are lazy. As long as you set `oveflow: hidden;` to the parent element, everything will be just great. This is what I mean:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oog4w08d/1/)

Comment: Click the Run if you have missed the animation ;)

Comment: wow I feel dumb now... had tryed it with % but it didn't work... This worked just fine!

Comment: Just to add this in case anyone in future uses this guide: I don't want to use much java as I am not secure enough in knowing it so I am using a pure CSS solution: 
`.overlay{
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0% 10%;
 height: 0%;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #000;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 -webkit-transition: 1.5s;
 -moz-transition: 1.5s;
 transition: 1.5s;
}
.parent-div:hover .overlay { 
 height: 64%;
 padding: 10%;
 opacity: 0.9;
 -webkit-transition: 1.5s;
 -moz-transition: 1.5s;
 transition: 1.5s;
} `

Answer (score 0):

I've came across this problem when struggling with bigg css libraries and elements that are sometimes hard to style around. 
This jQuery solution have helped me where I basicly make the width of an element follow an width of a target element width.

```
function resize_follower() {
    $(".follower").width($(".some-size").width());
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    resize_follower();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    resize_follower();
});
```

[Example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vpxarb2c/)